# Как добавить ссылку на изображение с помощью jQuery

Tags: изображения, jquery-ui

Есть такой код, как добавить к каждой картинке ссылку?

```
var object=[
  {label:"Изображение 1",url:"mountimg.jpg", description:"Закат в горах, Ергаки.", coord:{lt:"52.854413",ln:"93.367310"}},
  {label:"Изображение 2",url:"mountimg1.jpg", description:"Вид на безымянную гору с озера 'Круглое', Кузнецкий Алатау.", coord:{lt:"53.815653",ln:"89.283829"}},
  {label:"Изображение 3",url:"mountimg2.jpg", description:"Озеро 'Харлыкголь', Кузнецкий Алатау.", coord:{lt:"53.800245",ln:"89.268723"}},
  {label:"Изображение 4",url:"mountimg3.jpg", description:"Скала 'Два брата' (Парабола), Ергаки.", coord:{lt:"52.839225",ln:"93.397093"}}];


$("#image").autocomplete({source:object,select:function(event,ui){
  $("#wrap").css("display","block");
  $("#img").attr("src",ui.item.url);
  $("#desc").html(ui.item.description);
  $("#latitude").html(ui.item.coord.lt);
  $("#longitude").html(ui.item.coord.ln);
}});
```

Comment: Выложите в вопрос html код блока, с которым проводятся действия. Так-же поясните, что вы имеете ввиду, под словом ссылка? Тег `<a>`?

Comment: http://www.wisdomweb.ru/editor/wweditor.php?fname=jquid_autocomplete

Comment: да ,ссылка тег <a>

Answer (score 1):

## Тег `<a>`:

Добавьте ссылки в массив:

```
var object=[
 {... link: "http://site1.com", ...},
 {... link: "http://site2.com", ...},
 ...
];
```

Добавьте тег `a` в html-код, там где он должен быть:

```
<a id="link">
     <img id="img" src="mountimg.jpg" width="200" height="170" />
</a>
```

И подставьте `href` в эту ссылку:

```
$("#link").attr('href', ui.item.link);
```

Результат:

```js
var object=[
      {label:"Изображение 1",url:"mountimg.jpg", link:"http://site1.com", description:"Закат в горах, Ергаки.", coord:{lt:"52.854413",ln:"93.367310"}},
      {label:"Изображение 2",url:"mountimg1.jpg", link:"http://site2.com", description:"Вид на безымянную гору с озера 'Круглое', Кузнецкий Алатау.", coord:{lt:"53.815653",ln:"89.283829"}},
      {label:"Изображение 3",url:"mountimg2.jpg", link:"http://site3.com", description:"Озеро 'Харлыкголь', Кузнецкий Алатау.", coord:{lt:"53.800245",ln:"89.268723"}},
      {label:"Изображение 4",url:"mountimg3.jpg",  link:"http://site4.com", description:"Скала 'Два брата' (Парабола), Ергаки.", coord:{lt:"52.839225",ln:"93.397093"}}
];
$("#image").autocomplete({source:object,select:function(event,ui){
      $("#wrap").css("display","block");
      $("#img").attr("src",'http://www.wisdomweb.ru/editor/'+ui.item.url);
      $("#link").attr('href', ui.item.link);  
      $("#desc").html(ui.item.description);
      $("#latitude").html(ui.item.coord.lt);
      $("#longitude").html(ui.item.coord.ln);
}});
```

```html
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<p>Введите название изображения (введите к примеру "изо"): <input id="image" /></p>
<div id="wrap" style="display:none;font-size:1.2em;">
  <a id="link"><img id="img" src="mountimg.jpg" width="200" height="170" /></a><br /><br />
  <p><b>Описание:</b> <span id="desc"></span>
    <p id="cord"><b>Координаты месторасположения:</b> <br />Широта: <span id="latitude"></span> Долгота: <span id="longitude"></span></p>
</div>
```

## Onclick:

Вместо тегa `a` нужно поставить обработчик клика (ссылку запомним в дата-атрибуте):

```
$("#img").data('link', ui.item.link)
$("#img").click(function(){ window.location = $(this).data('link')});
```

Результат:

```js
var object=[
      {label:"Изображение 1",url:"mountimg.jpg", link:"http://site1.com", description:"Закат в горах, Ергаки.", coord:{lt:"52.854413",ln:"93.367310"}},
      {label:"Изображение 2",url:"mountimg1.jpg", link:"http://site2.com", description:"Вид на безымянную гору с озера 'Круглое', Кузнецкий Алатау.", coord:{lt:"53.815653",ln:"89.283829"}},
      {label:"Изображение 3",url:"mountimg2.jpg", link:"http://site3.com", description:"Озеро 'Харлыкголь', Кузнецкий Алатау.", coord:{lt:"53.800245",ln:"89.268723"}},
      {label:"Изображение 4",url:"mountimg3.jpg",  link:"http://site4.com", description:"Скала 'Два брата' (Парабола), Ергаки.", coord:{lt:"52.839225",ln:"93.397093"}}
];
$("#image").autocomplete({source:object,select:function(event,ui){
      $("#wrap").css("display","block");
      $("#img").data('link', ui.item.link)
      $("#img").click(function(){ window.location = $(this).data('link')});
      $("#img").attr("src",'http://www.wisdomweb.ru/editor/'+ui.item.url);
      $("#desc").html(ui.item.description);
      $("#latitude").html(ui.item.coord.lt);
      $("#longitude").html(ui.item.coord.ln);
}});
```

```html
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<p>Введите название изображения (введите к примеру "изо"): <input id="image" /></p>
<div id="wrap" style="display:none;font-size:1.2em;">
 <img id="img" src="mountimg.jpg" width="200" height="170" /><br /><br />
  <p><b>Описание:</b> <span id="desc"></span>
    <p id="cord"><b>Координаты месторасположения:</b> <br />Широта: <span id="latitude"></span> Долгота: <span id="longitude"></span></p>
</div>
```

Comment: спасибо,а можно вместо ссылки поставить onclick

Comment: @галям Обновил ответ

Comment: у меня есть картинка с  <img src="1.png"  onclick="fun_1(hh0)">  ,как этот onclick добавить к изображению 1,вместо первой ссылки?

Comment: @галям я уже ответил, читайте

Comment: не получается((

Comment: @галям Обработчик события  onclick ставится через функцию jQuery [`click()`](https://api.jquery.com/click/) я привел вам пример рабочего кода

Comment: посмотрите так правильно?                                                                  {label:"Изображение 1",url:"mountimg.jpg", link:"http://site1.com", onclick:"fun_1(hh0)",description:".", coord:{lt:"52.854413",ln:"93.367310"}},

$("#image").autocomplete({source:object,select:function(event,ui){
      $("#wrap").css("display","block");
      $("#img").data('onclick', ui.item.onclick)
      $("#img").click(function(){ window.location = $(this).data('onclick')});
      $("#img").attr("src",'http://www.wisdomweb.ru/editor/'+ui.item.url);
      $("#desc").html(ui.item.description);

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите ,что не так?

```js
var object=[
      {label:"Изображение 1",url:"mountimg.jpg", link:"fun_1(hh0)", description:"Закат в горах, Ергаки.", coord:{lt:"52.854413",ln:"93.367310"}},
      
];
$("#image").autocomplete({source:object,select:function(event,ui){
      $("#wrap").css("display","block");
      $("#img").data('link', ui.item.link)
      $("#img").click(function(){ window.location = $(this).data('link')});
      $("#img").attr("src",'http://www.wisdomweb.ru/editor/'+ui.item.url);
      $("#desc").html(ui.item.description);
      $("#latitude").html(ui.item.coord.lt);
      $("#longitude").html(ui.item.coord.ln);
}});
```

```html
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<p>Введите название изображения (введите к примеру "изо"): <input id="image" /></p>
<div id="wrap" style="display:none;font-size:1.2em;">
 <img id="img" src="mountimg.jpg" width="200" height="170" /><br /><br />
  <p><b>Описание:</b> <span id="desc"></span>
    <p id="cord"><b>Координаты месторасположения:</b> <br />Широта: <span id="latitude"></span> Долгота: <span id="longitude"></span></p>
</div>
```

Comment: глаз дергается уже